# Paint artifacts in Android

Tags: android, cordova

This is a PhoneGap app using v2.9.  I am using Android 4.2.1 Galaxy S3.  I have a swipe event that allows an enduser to scroll to the end of the graph, and back to the beginning.  There seems to be a paint issue where the graph is scrolled correctly, but an additional, nonclickable graph is left behind.  I have a video demonstrating:

http://youtu.be/4gpyIQhS04Q

Here is an even more frustrating thing: If I disable hardware acceleration in the AndroidManifest.xml, the issue does not occur, but if I perform the same test using a Razor Max running 4.2.2, the graphs do not even appear in the webview (with acceleration disabled).

Another odd thing is that it only happens to the topmost graph.  Ex: If i delete the blue graph, then the green graph displays the behavior, if I delete the green graph, then the yellow graph displays the behavior.

This was a dupe of: [Android WebView Hardware Rendering Weird Artifact Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099402/android-webview-hardware-rendering-weird-artifact-issue)

It turns out I was not putting the CSS on the correct element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the below to your CSS. It can increase performance and reduce ghosting, stuttering, and rendering issues.

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Comment: yeah, I tried that.  Seems to have worked for other people, but not for me :-(

Comment: nevermind!  I wasnt putting it up high enough in the elements!!