# Android views got messed up upon bringing back to foreground with HA enabled

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, hardware-acceleration

I have no idea why the view got messed up upon bringing back app from background to foreground. This only happens when hardware acceleration is enabled in my android manifest. If I disabled HA, the view restore is normal.

Portion of my Android manifest with HA enabled:

```
<application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
...
```

Please check the screenshot of restored views below (I blurred certain portion), you will see the top navigation bar's icon got stretched, bottom tab bar is gone and the center webview is not rendered, the app still functions with my finger taps and functions normally:

P.S. these are from my Nougat (Android 7.0) Nexus 5X

[image]
[image]

Comment: After some search, I found it is related to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099402/android-webview-hardware-rendering-weird-artifact-issue

Answer (score 0):

After googling around, it seems a known problem for restoring HA webview upon bringing to foreground: http://www.jianshu.com/p/3e63aa3b80d7
(it is a Chinese site)

I manage to workaround the issue by disabling HA in all of the webviews by looping through the root view of the activity upon bring the app into background:

```
public void recursivelyDeactivateHA(ViewGroup parent) {
    for (int i = parent.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if (child != null && child instanceof WebView && child.isHardwareAccelerated()) {
            Logger.getLogger().e("disable HA for child: " + child);
            child.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            recursivelyDeactivateHA((ViewGroup) child);
        }
    }
}
```

and then reload all of the webviews by:

```
webView.reload();
```