# Android Webview Rendering Issue

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, rendering, samsung-mobile

[image: error2]
[image: error1]

Since yesterday, there have been a lot of users experiencing issues like the screenshot.
The page is a full page web view, and the displayed content is web content.

The common thing among users who have experienced this problem is that they are using Android 10 version of Samsung phone.

I guess it's a webview rendering issue, but it can't be reproduced.

Was there any update related to the webview yesterday? I tested it with various versions of webview, but it can't be reproduced.

Does anyone have any of these issues? Or, if someone solved it, please share the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Some of the users of my app are experiencing the same issue on Android 10 (cordova based app here).

Did you find any solution?

Comment: @qpwr check answer from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64427118/2776456) if you using cordova ionic app

Comment: I solved issue with remove some animation css. 


I think this issue similar [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099402/android-webview-hardware-rendering-weird-artifact-issue) when using hardware hardwareaccelerated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue with remove some animation css. I think this issue similar this link when using hardware hardwareaccelerated

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with an ionic app (cordova-android 9.0.0) on android 10 devices (Huawei mate 20 pro). On other devices the app works fine (pixel 2). At the moment I can't say what actually causes this issue. I fixed this issue by just rebuilding the app in prod/release mode and by adding following lines to the proguard file:

```
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.** { *; }
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.*
```

Comment: My case isn't ionic so I can't solve issue with this answer...